# session variable user_id not being updated

Tags: php, session

I used to do that to test if the user is logged in, and if so display his/her content:

```
if (login_check($conn) == true) {
  // show content here
}
```

But since it failed sometimes and I wanted to know why, I changed it to

```
$loginErro = login_error($conn);
if (!$loginErro) {
  // show content here
}
```

so I could get a number to know what the error was. But since then the errors increased. Many times the page says I'm not logged in, when in fact I'm logged in. I need to press F5 to refresh the correct session variable. The line that triggers the error in the login_error function is

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    return 4;
}
```

Why my user_id is not being updated, mostly in the first time after a while (the session's cookie timeout, probably)?

EDIT: Somehow I could isolate the problem. When calling window.open() function, I was using

```
window.open('some_php_file.php','');
```

It opens multiple copies of the same php file, but loads them all ok. Then I changed it to

```
window.open('some_php_file.php','some_php_file.php');
```

to prevent opening multiple copies of the same window. Now, I open the first copy ok. When I click the button to open the window again, it is logging off from the system! Still trying to understand what's going on...

Comment: Are you using ajax to authenticate the user, and after that are you refreshing/reloading the whole page or redirecting to other page or just refreshing the session variable?

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['user_id'] = value;`? Without this it is ***NEVER*** going to be set ;)

Comment: @AlbertoRussell I login in the main page, it shows content ok. When I open some other pages, sometimes the session don't load.

Comment: @SamSwift, I set it, because the main page is logged in. The second opened page is the one that used to connect right away before, and now requires a F5 *sometimes*.